# Run-time error 438 will not trigger error handler

Tags: vba

I am trying to write a code that will iterate through the windows shells until it finds Internet Explorer, which will have a web page that contains that classname. The problem is that the code if it can not set adauga_pariu it will give me the 438 run-time error and will not trigger the error handler.

```
i = 0


Set shellWins = New ShellWindows

If shellWins.Count > 0 Then
  For i = 0 To shellWins.Count

  Set ie = shellWins.Item(i)

  On Error GoTo error

  Set adauga_ron = ie.document.getElementsByClassName("KambiBC-outcome-item")

    If adauga_ron.Length > 0 Then
       GoTo ok    
    End If

error:
    i = i + 1
  Next i

End If

ok:
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't handling your errors correctly.  Once you handle them, you need to `Resume`, otherwise you are still in "error-handling" mode and any new error cannot be handled.

```
'i = 0  '<-- this isn't needed - the "For i = 0" will initialise i to 0
Set shellWins = New ShellWindows
If shellWins.Count > 0 Then
    For i = 0 To shellWins.Count
        Set ie = shellWins.Item(i)

        On Error GoTo error
        Set adauga_ron = ie.document.getElementsByClassName("KambiBC-outcome-item")

        If adauga_ron.Length > 0 Then
            On Error GoTo 0 ' To avoid having later errors coming back to this code
            GoTo ok    
        End If
        On Error GoTo 0 'Always disable error handling when you don't need it
errorContinue:
        'i = i + 1 '<-- don't do this - you are already using a "For i" loop
    Next i
End If
MsgBox "No match found"
Exit Sub

error:
    Resume errorContinue 'Always "Resume" from your error handler

ok:
```

Comment: Thank you, this does the job, the only thing is that it will go to ok even if it iterates trough all i and does not set adauga_pariu.

Comment: Your code was automatically dropping into the code after the `ok:` label.  If you don't want to do that, just change the `GoTo ok` statement which is processed after the `If shellWins.Count > 0 Then`'s `End If` with whatever you want to do if no match is made.  (Perhaps an `Exit Sub`?)